# I am trying to compile java code in Tibco BW designer but getting error

Tags: java, tibco-business-works

I am trying to compile java code in tibco bw designer but im facing issue,
Note: \temp\javaCode\listFilesInFolders.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Please assist.

Comment: *"Please assist."* - Follow the directions given in the error message!

Comment: javac -Xlint:unchecked